# How to put values from dictionary to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to get all values from section in my `ini` file (via configparser) as a variable:

```
hue310section = dict(parser.items('HUE_310'))

for keys, value in hue310section.items():
    pairs = keys + ' = ' + value
    print(pairs)
```

it gave me `partnewfilepath = http://some_site:PORT/about`, but I don't know how to import this output as an python variable, that I can use `partnewfilepath` somewhere in my code. Of course one section will have more values than only one, and I want to change all that in variable. I trying to find solution but I think I miss something because my knowledge about python is not enough yet. I think I need to rebuilt my `for` statement but don't have a clue how to do it in this particular problem.

My config.ini file looks like:

```
[HUE_310]
partNewFilePath = ${common:domain}/about
otherValues = something
nextvalue = another something
```

UPDATE:

I think I need to elaborate more about what I want to achieve. In other part of my code I check version of site I want to process. If the site has, let say version 3.10 I want to get all values from section `HUE_310` from my `ini` file, and use them as python variable. Rest of my code use those variable and if the site version will change I can get values from other section from my `ini` file and get those values to python variable and use them. I assume that some variables will change from version to version and that's why I want to prepare my code to check this. Also it gives me some freedom to modify some variable if site will change.
I hope it is now more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a new variable or a for loop, you already have `hue310section` dict.

You can just use

```
hue310section['partNewFilePath']
```

which will be equal to

```
"http://some_site:PORT/about"
```

Note that after `hue310section = dict(parser.items('HUE_310'))`
, `otherValues` and `nextvalue` keys will also be defined.

Comment: But I need more generic solution. I assume that I don't know what is in config file sections. I just want to import all from particular section as a variable to use them in my code somewhere. So I need to take all from section HUE_310 and put those as an variable in my code when I find that I need those only from that section.

Comment: @heniekk: And the `dict` will have exactly this information. You can iterate over they keys or you can get can just the key you need. There's no added benefit of defining variables.

Comment: I edited my question and elaborate more what I want to achieve with my code. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

```
from configobj import ConfigObj

parser_data = ConfigObj(config_path)
current = parser_data['HUE_310'].get('partNewFilePath', 'http://www.default.com')
```

config_path is path to the file

http://www.default.com is the default value in case that particular key is not found.

Comment: There's a special domain named 'example.com' cf https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved